# JSON decode and encode for saving memory

Tags: javascript, object, encode

I want to make request and want to send big json object. but because request is big, I am getting error 413 Request Entity Too Large.
So I need an algorithm for it. Or It will good to stream this data?

Comment: saving memory? with json? please explain a bit more.

Comment: The best way to save memory is to analyze your data structure and use bit fields where ever possible. Other than analyzing your data structures, there is no way to do it. If you want to shorten, network transfer, consider gzipping the data server side before sending the response. In your updated question, it seems that you would want to GZIP the data at compression level 9 (highest), prior to sending the data.

Comment: Ok so since its a big JSON You need to encode it to be a smaller JSON?

Comment: maybe you are looking for something like http://web-resource-optimization.blogspot.it/2011/06/json-compression-algorithms.html https://github.com/WebReflection/json.hpack , btw if you have to transmit a huge packet probably you have to break your packet in more chunk

Answer (score 0):

Send only what you need! JSON.stringify() only removes white space. there is no encoding done to create a JSON object. You can compress the string using a ZIP library such as JSONC to get about 80% compression.

I don't believe GZip is possible from Browser to server (I could be wrong).

But it would be better to send only the data that you need, if you don't need it all.

I've seen situations where the developer uses single character property names and methods, then uses a "map" to reach the properties and methods server side.